# Sharepoint 2007 - SingleLineOfText Field Autosuggest

Tags: sharepoint-2007

is there any possibility in Sharepoints out of the box festures to enable something like an autosuggest field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported out of the box but you can use the [Autocomplete Text Field](http://smarttools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Autocomplete%20Text%20Field) available on CodePlex.

[image: Autocomplete Text Field]

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks!